# changing background image of div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to change the background of the div when I hover over the image, but somehow it's not detecting image though the URL is displayed in the console. I have no idea of jQuery. Thank you.

```js
function upDate(previewPic) {
  var divblock = document.getElementById('image');
  var img = previewPic.src;
  console.log(img);
  divblock.style.backgroundImage = img;
  divblock.innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>
<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
```

Comment: Your code seems to work, as I understand it. The only error is because you've not provided the `unDo()` function in the example

Comment: your code works okay as @RoryMcCrossan said. 
  just remove the onmouseout() because you don't require it, anyhow on hover of another image will upDate() is always going to fire. 

or else create a blank function and return true in unDo()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the image source with `url` like `divblock.style.backgroundImage = "url('url of the source')";`

```js
function upDate(previewPic) {
  var divblock = document.getElementById('image');
  var img = previewPic.src;
  divblock.classList.add('hoverDiv');
  divblock.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + img + ')';
  divblock.innerHTML = previewPic.alt;
}

function unDo() {}
```

```css
.hoverDiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  Hover over an image below to display here.
</div>
<img class="preview" alt="Styling with a Bandana" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
<img class="preview" alt="With My Boy" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
<img class="preview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt="Young Puppy" onmouseover="upDate(this)" onmouseout="unDo()">
```

Comment: Why is the URL quotes used in quite a weird way. Thanks for modification.

Comment: it is because `img` is a variable and you need to concat with `url`